tikzpicture environment makes \noindent have no effect
See this MWE please:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\begin{document}

% \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%   \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}};
% \end{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\noindent
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \mode_leave_vertical:
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2cm } { Classification }
  \uline { \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2.4cm } { \hfill 1234 \hfill } }
  \hfill
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1.67cm } { Secret-level }
  \uline { \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2.4cm } { \hfill AAAA \hfill } }
\end{minipage}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}

If I uncomment the tikzpicture part, the first minipage is indented even though there is \noindent before it.


Is there any particular reason for complicating your life with expl3 in this case?

@egreg Actually I'm maintaining a thesis template using LaTeX3. The MWE is just the extraction of some code from the cls file.

The construct is overcomplicated anyway.

The tikzpicture begins a paragraph, so \noindent has no effect.
Move it before the \begin{tikzpicture} (I added \ignorespaces to avoid undesired spaces before the minipage, but you can also use a comment char %).
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}\ignorespaces
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \mode_leave_vertical:
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2cm } { Classification }
  \uline { \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2.4cm } { \hfill 1234 \hfill } }
  \hfill
  \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1.67cm } { Secret-level }
  \uline { \hbox_to_wd:nn { 2.4cm } { \hfill AAAA \hfill } }
\end{minipage}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}



Thank you!@jlab

I'm not sure you gain much by using expl3 in such a case. To be more direct, you just overcomplicate things, because LaTeX already has the required tools.
The top minipage nested in \fbox should be \framebox. Be careful with the endlines, also.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}% <--- important
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\framebox[\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxrule}][s]{%
  \strut
  \,Classification
  \uline{\makebox[2.4cm][c]{1234}}%
  \hfill
  Secret-level
  \uline{\makebox[2.4cm][c]{AAAA}}%
}
\endgroup

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 
ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\end{document}

The width of the \framebox is corrected by the \fboxrule, so it's not overfull.
The \noindent should go before the tikzpicture.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}% <--- important
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\framebox[\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxrule}][s]{%
  \strut
  \,Classification
  \uline{\makebox[2.4cm][c]{1234}}%
  \hfill
  Secret-level
  \uline{\makebox[2.4cm][c]{AAAA}}%
}
\endgroup

\bigskip

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 
ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

\end{document}


